# What means exit code 139 in Dart console application?

Tags: dart-native-extension, dart

Console program written in Dart that invoke `native function` exit with code `139`.

Dart VM does not display error messages.

- What happened?
- Where I can find documentation about exit code 139?
- Why not displayed `stack trace` of Dart VM code?

P.S.

I purposely did not give an example because it occurs repeatedly.

I can not understand why the program that terminated abnormal does not display error messages.

Does this means that error code `139` is unhandled error in Dart VM without provided text of error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it means that your program died with signal 11 (SIGSEGV on Linux and most other UNIXes), also known as segmentation fault.

In your case your extension has raised this and brought down the VM hard, so this is the only thing the console can report.

Check your code for null/invalid pointer access etc.

You can use cerr to log trace messages into the console from your extension e.g.

std::cerr << "Im here " << std::endl;